# How do I create folders that could not be opened by explorer?

Tags: winapi

I have a project, how to create a folder that can not be accessed by explorer (can not be opened). Please help me. Thank you

Comment: This would be malware. In any case, the question is ill framed. Security constrains what users can do, not what programs can do. There's no way to secure objects to differentiate between the program that accesses them. What counts is the user that accesses the object.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a god mode folder :)

Rename it into `folder_name.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`, and voila, it can't be opened by explorer, at least not with the original contents.

Obviously, that won't work if the system is configured to show extensions (the folder can be just renamed back). Also, it can easily be accessed by third party tools, such as WinRAR.